# Dont know how to lock the center of a widget and separate it from the others

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I'm creating an app with the main menu and different minigames, I'm starting with Flutter, so I don't understand properly how to manage the widgets properly, in this case, I have simplified the code because what I want is to understand the hierarchy, and how to place the widgets properly

```
child: Scaffold(
    body: Container( 
            child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
                Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
        
                    child: Text(_element, style: new TextStyle( fontSize: 28.0, color: Colors.black), textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                flex: 1, 
                child: Container(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text('Next', style: new TextStyle( fontSize: 100.0, color: Colors.black)),
                    onPressed: () {
                        getNextElement();
                    },
                    ),

                ),
                ),
            ],
            ),
        ),
    )
```

With this code I get this:

**What I have**
[image]

I want to understand how to use widgets properly and in which order.
And my problem is that I want the button at the bottom and the text in the center, and when I press the button the text changes so when it is a longer phrase the size of the text container changes and it expands to the top of it but without changing the width, but I want it to be centered and when the text is bigger I want it to expand up and down like this:

**Objective:**
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note that it's _one_ question per post. Please [edit] your question to only include one question. And ask the other ones as different posts on SO

Comment: Have you tried the `Center` widget? It'll take all the space in the Scaffold and then place its children at the center.